# Quick PROLOG enquiry

Tags: prolog

I have predicates as follows

```
dur(a,1).
dur(b,2).
dur(c,3).
dur(d,4).
```

Say I want to add the elements of a list [a,b,c] so sum = 6.
How do I access the value associated with the variable?

Because something like this

```
len([],0).
len([H|T], Sum) :-
   len(T, Rest),
   Sum is H + Rest.
```

doesn't work, it works fine for [1,2,3] but not at all for [a,b,c] which makes sense, but I don't have a clue how to make it work for list len([a,b,c],Sum).

Comment: If you have the atom `a`, you can get it's value by querying `dur(a, Value)`. If you have a variable X, you can get the value of whatever `X` is by querying `dur(X, Value)`. You can use this in your `len` predicate to sum the values rather than attempting to sum the atoms themselves.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I access the value associated with the variable?

You must 'join' deep in the loop, where the actual computing take place

```
len([],0).
len([H|T], Sum) :-
   dur(H, V),  % 'hardcoded' join
   Sum is V + Rest.
   len(T, Rest),
```

now the true problem is apparent.

Since a join is such a basic operation in Prolog - really, it does very little otherwise -it's difficult to write - and so reuse - algorithms truly independent from the *naming* of the data.

Usually 'second order' programming can help, massaging the data to adapt to more generic context. Like

```
len(Keys, Len) :- maplist(dur, Keys, Nums), sum_list(Nums, Len).
```

SWI-Prolog autoloads maplist/3 from library([apply](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply)), some other Prolog could require you to explicitly load it...